# Tkinter - Change Frames with Notebook

Tags: python, tkinter

I have frame and inside i have Notebook (Tabs). Each tab represent diffrent frame.
Besides the Notebook, i also have Menu. What i'm trying to do is when i click on the menu, for example 'file' , I want to change the current Frame with a new Frame.

I'm having problem with the logic, because i used OOP to build the Notebook.

**Code**

```
class Layout:
def __init__(self, window):
    self.window = window
    window.title('Insta Bot')
    window.geometry('800x600')

    # menu config
    menu = Menu(window)
    sub_menu = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
    menu.add_cascade(label='Main', menu=sub_menu)
    sub_menu.add_command(label='Accounts')
    sub_menu.add_command(label='Exit')
    window.config(menu=menu)

    # tab config
    tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)

    hash_tag_tab = TabHashTag(tab_control)
    followers_tab = TabFollowers(tab_control)
    location_tab = TabLocation(tab_control)

    tab_control.add(hash_tag_tab, text='Hash Tag')
    tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
    tab_control.add(followers_tab, text='Followers')
    tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
    tab_control.add(location_tab, text='Location')
    tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

    # status bar config
    status_bar = Label(window, text="status bar", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
    status_bar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
```

Here I'm creating the Menu,Notebook and also the status bar.
Also i push to the Tab control 3 Frame classes (hash_tag_tab,followers_tab ...).
What i want to do is when the user click on the menu, to change the frames between Notebook to other frame.

I understand that i need to use a method called `tkraise()`, but i cant figure the logic,how to do that.
Any idea how can i use it in this code?
I hope the question is clear, if not please hit me up.

Comment: [Switch between two frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557028/7414759)

Comment: I have seen this answer, but it doesn't help me with the problem that i have. How do i combine the Notebook (Tabs) with the frames?

Comment: As it stands you create three tabs with one single `Frame`. There is nothing to switch?